# Filter Rest API AssignedToId

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest, filter

I've been trying to filters with rest API, but I seem to be struggeling with easy requests. So this one works without any problems

http://myserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle%28'Tickets'%29/items?$select=AssignedToId

If I try to filter based on this property I receive an error

http://myserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle%28'Tickets'%29/items?$filter=AssignedToId eq 1

Why is this the case? Isn't it the case that you can filter any property you can find in in the response? Please help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will sound crazy, but change it to filter on "AssignedTo" but keep "AssignedToId" in the select:

```
http://myserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle%28'Tickets'%29/items?$select=AssignedToId&$filter=AssignedTo eq 1
```

The other way to do it would be to use the $expand param:

```
http://myserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle%28'Tickets'%29/items?$expand=AssignedTo/Id&$select=AssignedTo/Id,AssignedTo/LastName&$filter=AssignedTo/Id eq 1
```

EDIT: improved readability

Comment: More info: http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/

Comment: It really is crazy, but thanks for pointing it out. TaskGroupId behaves in the same way (not sure what it does anyway) so at least it's kind of consitent ;)

Comment: One more question: If AssignedTo allows multiple values, I can't filter those anymore just like it's the case with view query, right?

Comment: I know you can use and/or operators along with (parens) to group parts of the query in $filter.  I added a column called "People" that allows the user to select more than one person.  I want list items that have both the userID 1 AND 2 in that column, or items that have userId 3:

http://myTestSite.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('zShellyTest')/items?$select=Title,People/ID,People/FirstName,People/LastName&$expand=People/ID&$top=10&$filter=(People/Id eq 1 and People/Id eq 2) or People/Id eq 3